# Issues with the format of .cpanel.yml file when trying to deploy cpanel git repository to directory.

Tags: linux, git, cpanel

- I am using a cpanel web administration system.
- With it i create a git repository.
- I am able to push my local code to that git repository.

The problem arises when i attempt to deploy the code in the repository to a production directory on my server.

According to [cpanel documentation about deployment](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git+-+Deployment), in order to deploy, a git repository must contain a `.cpanel.yml` file which is committed with the following example data:

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
    - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp style.css $DEPLOYPATH
```

I have tried various different configurations of this file in order to be able to deploy but couldn't get it to work. I cannot find any more documentation or any further develop examples or sample files.

The relevant structure of my linux server is thus:

```
home/<username>/
    - git/gitrepo/
        - all of the git files and folders
    - public_html/<app_folder>/
```

I would like to deploy all of the files and folders in the git repository into the `public_html/<app_folder>/` directory.

I have tried the following different configurations:

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/<username>/public_html/<app_folder>
        - / $DEPLOYPATH

---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
    - /bin/cp  $DEPLOYPATH

---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
    - / index.html $DEPLOYPATH // Tried just one file to see if would work but it didn't.
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
    - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH // Tried just one file to see if would work but it didn't.
```

Comment: Hey Aviya, is your issue resolved?? if fixed can you please tell me which one it worked??

Comment: @AmanJham The accepted answer worked well for me and solved my issue. Did it not work for you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So this is basically a bash script that CPanel runs when you update your repo stored on the server. the layout in your case should be:

**Please remove all "# comments" if you are copying the example or it might not work**

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/<username>/public_html/<app_folder>
        - /bin/cp <file_name> $DEPLOYPATH #Copy specific file to destination from root
        - /bin/cp /<sub_folder>/<file_name> $DEPLOYPATH #copy specific file from source sub folder
        - /bin cp * $DEPLOYPATH #copy all from root 
        - /bin cp /<sub_folder>/* $DEPLOYPATH #copy all from sub folder root
```

So the above should work for you.....but.....

If you are doing the whole root to destination then here is the one I use to just copy all.

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/<user_name>/public_html #Add /<sub_folder> if required
    - /bin/cp -r * $DEPLOYPATH
```

- /bin/cp  "copy command"
- -r "recursive include sub folder / files"
- '*' "all"

Remember to add `/<sub_folder>` if you need an app folder other than public_html

You can get the file from my repo:

https://github.com/FrancoisGeyser/cPanel-yml.git

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Francois, thank you very much for this thorough answer. I just wanted to say that I'm super busy and will only have time to go through this later on. But i will definitely do so and if it work i will be sure to mark it as the answer. For now i upvoted you.  (It can just be quite annoying when you give a good answer and go on ignored so I wanted to let you know that this isn't the case! and welcome to stack-overflow!)

Comment: WORKS! Of course Friday night presented the best opportunity to finally check it haha. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: The One thing confuse me a bit @Francois should we have to add it to our code folder top directory or Cpanel top-level directory. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Hamad. It needs to be in your code folder top directory / root.

Comment: ```/bin/cp -r * $DEPLOYPATH``` will put your .git folder online, usually that's not wanted